# I want to write test cases for function with parameter using jest

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, jestjs

I have one function which is accepting one parameter in yyyy-mm-dd format. I am taking todays date and comparing that date with date received in parameter.

I want to write test cases using jest, Firstly it should check date passed in parameter is in yyyy-mm-dd format.

So my function is roughly looks like:

```
function dateFunction(parameter in yyyy-mm-dd format){

today = new Date() // it is taking todays date.
convertedDate = converting parameter date into date format.
 
if (today === convertedDate){
// then do something
}
else {
   // do something
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
test("The function parameter should be in yyyy-mm-dd format", () => {
    const dateToBeChecked = '2021-12-17';
    const dateFormat = (/([12]\d{3}-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01]))/.test(dateToBeChecked));
    expect(dateFunction(dateToBeChecked)).toBe(dateFormat)
})
```